# Renaming field in attribute table via PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, rename

How can I rename a field in PyQGIS?

I tried:

```py
for field in layer.pendingFields():

    if field.name() == 'old':

        layer.startEditing()
        oldname = field.name()
        field.setName('new')
        newname = field.name()
        print(u'Old name: {}, New name: {}'.format(oldname,newname))
        layer.commitChanges()
```

This code prints 'Old name: old, New name: new', but in the attribute table the field name is still *'old'*.

Comment: What does it do? Do you get errors or does it do something else? Please [edit] your question to include this info

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9):

### PyQGIS 3

Use this one:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name() == 'old_fieldname':

        with edit(layer):
            idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
            layer.renameAttribute(idx, 'new_fieldname')
```

Or try this function:

```py
def rename_dp_field(rlayer, oldname, newname):
  findex = rlayer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex(oldname)
  if findex != -1:
    rlayer.dataProvider().renameAttributes({findex: newname})
    rlayer.updateFields()
```

Answer (score 5):

I think the [`QgsField::setName()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsField.html#a5c42dee74115fb78383b3140c023fcbe) method is only used for creating **new fields**.

If you want to **rename** your field, you can use [`QgsVectorLayer::renameAttribute()`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ad45989d6c5547499fe9ab95e75240579) method in QGIS 2.16 and above:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

for field in layer.pendingFields():
    if field.name() == 'old':

        with edit(layer):
            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
            layer.renameAttribute(idx, 'new')
```

Comment: I used this code to update the field names 3 times sequentially, and it worked flawlessly the first two times. The third attempt at renaming the field yielded a 'layer not editable' error, which is strange considering the layer was edited twice immediately before then. Do you have any insight for why this is occurring?

Comment: If I change the 'with edit(layer)' line to 'layer.startEditing()', and then unindent the rest of the code, there are no problems updating the final field. Not sure why this is happening, but thankfully everything is working as anticipated now.

Comment: @GIS_Canuck - That is strange, not sure why `with edit(layer)` is a problem. Sounds like a bug to me. You could consider posting a [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/projects/qgis) with a reproducible method but glad you found another method :)

Comment: in QGis 3, QgsVectorLayer.fieldNameIndex is replaced by fields().lookupField() or fields().indexFromName() (see [here](https://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_QgsVectorLayer)). In this example, replace `idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())` by `idx = layer.pendingFields().indexFromName(field.name())`

Comment: It doesn't work for 2.84

Comment: @ChetanVashisth - Is that 2.8.4? The method should work for 2.16 onwards, could you not use the latest QGIS 3 version?

Comment: I am currently using a script in QGIS 2.84 WIen not 2.8.4 so mine is is the previous version of 2.18 LTR so i am unable to rename the fields and still trying to find something from last 2 days. Just let me know any alternative if you have any info about.

Comment: @ChetanVashisth - I think it would be better if you asked this as [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and reference this post to show you tried this method and it did not work. Include your script and describe whether you receive any errors or if the field doesn't get renamed.

Answer (score 2):

`edit(layer)` may cause trouble in a "standalone" script, I got an error `name 'edit' is not defined` so I found another way. I made this example with an `activeLayer()` :

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Open editing session
layer.startEditing()

# Rename field
for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name() == 'oldName':
        idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        layer.renameAttribute(idx, 'newName')

# Close editing session and save changes
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: also when `from qgis.core import edit` ?

Comment: I've never try with this import