# Rename fields of shapefile using PyQGIS 3

Tags: python, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am using the following script through QGIS 3.4 "Python Console" to rename field names of shapefiles. The input will be a CSV file with 1st row - shapefile name, 2nd row - old field name, 3rd row - new field name. Also, I have used this code in QGIS 2.18 (got the code from [Renaming field in attribute table via PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241149/renaming-field-in-attribute-table-via-pyqgis))  and slightly modified w.r.t Python 3 specifications.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, 
                      QVariant)
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing, 
                       QgsVectorLayer,     
                       QgsProject,     
                       QgsApplication,
                       QgsFeature,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsFields,
                       QgsField,
                       QgsGeometry,
                       QgsPoint,
                       QgsPointXY,
                       QgsRectangle,
                       QgsWkbTypes,
                       QgsSpatialIndex,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterField,
                       QgsProcessingParameterString,
                       QgsProcessingParameterBoolean,
                       QgsProcessingParameterNumber,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFile,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink)

from osgeo import gdal,osr,ogr
from os import path
import csv, os

csvpath = r"D:\Test\ved\rename_fld.csv"
with open(csvpath, "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)    

    for row in reader:
        one = row[0]
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(one,'','ogr')
        two = row[1]
        fromfld = QgsField(two).name()
        three = row[2]
        tofld = QgsField(three).name()
        for field in layer.fields():
            if field.name() == fromfld:
                try:
                    with edit(layer):
                        idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
                        layer.renameAttribute(idx, tofld)
                        print ("Changed Successfully")
                except Exception as ex:
                    print(ex)
```

Code runs without any issues and name is getting changed properly.

But if I run the code through processing toolbox as python script, I am getting "NameError". Below is the code I've used and the error it's throwing

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):

    # We add the input File Parameter.
    self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile(self.INPUT,self.tr('csv File'),0,'csv'))

def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    inputFile = self.parameterAsFile(parameters, self.INPUT, context)


    with open(inputFile, "r") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        for row in reader:
            one = str(row[0])
            layer = QgsVectorLayer(one,"","ogr")
            two = str(row[1])
            fromfld = QgsField(two).name()
            three = str(row[2])
            tofld = QgsField(three).name()

            for field in layer.fields():
                if field.name() == fromfld:
                    with edit(layer):
                        idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
                        layer.renameAttribute(idx, tofld)
                        print ("Changed Successfully")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 84, in processAlgorithm
NameError: name 'edit' is not defined

Execution failed after 0.15 seconds
```

Comment: Are you importing all the same modules in your second script as you are in your first? I would guess that perhaps running the code in the console is performing some imports in the background which is not being done when executing from the toolbox. Can you look up where `edit()` is being defined?

Comment: Both answers by @GeoGyro and @bonzinor solve your problem. You should import `qgis.core.edit` or you should start/end editing session manually using `startEditing` and  `commitChanges` . In QGIS Python Console, you don't need import `edit` method because it is imported by default.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error `name 'edit' is not defined` so I found another way. I made this example with an `activeLayer()` :

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Open editing session
layer.startEditing()

# Rename field
for field in layer.fields():
    if field.name() == 'oldName':
        idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(field.name())
        layer.renameAttribute(idx, 'newName')

# Close editing session and save changes
layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the `qgis.core.edit` class.

```
from qgis.core import edit
```