# Rename Attribute field in pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis

layer.renameAttribute(0,'xxx')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'renameAttribute'

Can you get me solution for this error?

Comment: The [QgsVectorLayer::renameAttribute()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ad45989d6c5547499fe9ab95e75240579) method was introduced in QGIS 2.16. I'm guessing you're using an earlier version?

Comment: yes i'm using 2.14.3

Comment: Could you update to a more recent version (e.g. 2.18)? Otherwise you could try the method posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/156262/how-to-rename-field-names-in-a-shapefile-attribute-table-without-table-manager-u).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Try this piece of code. It worked for me.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for field in layer.pendingFields():
    if field.name() == 'old':
        with edit(layer):
            idx = layer.fieldNameIndex(field.name())
            layer.renameAttribute(idx, 'new')
```

Comment: no tried this too,but same error is generating every time,do i need to import ant file for this to run?

Comment: This code is based on QGIS 3.0 not on 2.0 which causes the error in QGIS < 3.0